# Facebook Login issue - New users of iOS app unable to login via FB connect

Tags: php, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having issues with an IOS app that integrates with Facebook OpenGraph API & uses iOS & PHP v3.2 sdks  .. My problem is that new users are not registering on the app and hence no user_id is created and the app crashes when it tries to carry out a function .

It looks like the issue is with FB authorisation as the new user is not inserted into the DB, but the user details are received and stored locally on the app, but then when a query is called from the app it goes and checks the db for the user_id but does not find one and fails.

I can't see any auth exceptions & no errors are sent back from Facebook request. But it seems like the json returned has an issue .   Could someone tell me how I an view this json? This has only occurred since April/May .. No issue with login previously for new users before this. thanks

Comment: Hi. You should edit your question and paste the relevant code, so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

> But it seems like the json returned has an issue […] This has only occurred since April/May

Probably has something to do with this, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_changes:

> [Oauth Access Token] Format - The response format of https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token returned when you exchange a code for an access_token now return valid JSON instead of being URL encoded. The new format of this response is {"access_token": {TOKEN}, "token_type":{TYPE}, "expires_in":{TIME}}. We made this update to be compliant with section 5.1 of RFC 6749.

API version 2.3 was released on March 25th, 2015, so that would match what you said about when it started occurring.

Now the PHP SDK v3 is way old – if you want to keep using that, you will have to find out which method(s) are relevant here, and modify the code so that it properly handles the return data as JSON.

The current PHP SDK v5 handles this correctly on its own, but it is completely different from the v3 one. So upgrading that might be a larger task.

If your app only uses pre-v2.3 functionality, you could also try and make your app use v2.2 (in the SDK initialization), that will be available until March 25, 2017.